# How to configure Squid connection|read|write timeout per Request instead of Globally

Tags: http, proxy, squid

**Setup**

Suppose I have two different HTTP clients using the same Squid instance.

The first client, named ClientA, has an aggressive Http read/write and connection timeout of 5 seconds. The other Client, named ClientB, has a very relax timeout of 120 seconds.

My Squid server configurations looks like that:

```
connect_timeout 1 minute
read_timeout 1 minute
write_timeout 1 minute
```

**Scenario 1**

The ClientA, sends a request to ServerX (through Squid) that will wait 45 seconds before accepting the connection and then immediately answers back.

**Question 1**

The ClientA will timeout after 5 seconds, but will Squid notice that and close the outbound the connection or wait for ServerX response (in 40~ seconds) and fail to write back the result to the ClientA that is no longer listening?

**Scenario 2**

The ClientB, sends a request to ServerY (through Squid) that will wait 61 seconds before accepting the connection and then immediately answers back.

**Question 2**

The ClientB will NOT timeout, but Squid should timeout after 60 seconds and send an Http Timeout 408 to the ClientB, right?

**Global question**

Is there any way to setup Squid so we can set the timeouts by Request instead of globally at the service level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important note: squid's behavior regarding timeouts can change depending on the protocol used. In the case of HTTPS, it cannot inspect the tunneled connection's HTTP headers so it cannot honor any of the `Connection`, `Proxy-Connection`, or `Keep-Alive: timeout=xx` values.

**Scenario 1**

Squid will close the outbound connection as soon as it notices the client going away.

**Scenario 2**

Squid will indeed time out, but the result will depend on the protocol used. In the case of HTTP, it will return "`504 Gateway Time-out`" and add an additional header "`X-Squid-Error: ERR_READ_TIMEOUT 0`".

In the case of HTTPS, it will simply close the connection, because it cannot read or inject headers that would be meaningful to the client.

**Global question**

Not in the squid configuration itself. If you want fine-grained control over your persistent connections' timeouts, you should do so in your clients.

For the record, here are the time-out settings squid will try to honor for persistent connections:

client <-> squid: 
client_persistent_connections, persistent_request_timeout

squid<->server: 
server_persistent_connections, pconn_timeout, read_timeout (for HTTPS)